# Why SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is not working with this machine learning model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a .csv database file which looks like this:

```
              Day   Hour  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  ...  N14  N15  N16  N17  N18  N19  N20
0      1996-03-18  15:00   4   9  10  16  21  ...   48   62   66   68   73   76   78
1      1996-03-19  15:00   6  12  15  19  28  ...   63   64   67   69   71   75   77
2      1996-03-21  15:00   2   4   6   7  15  ...   52   54   69   72   73   75   77
3      1996-03-22  15:00   3   8  15  17  19  ...   49   60   61   64   67   68   75
4      1996-03-25  15:00   2  10  11  14  18  ...   55   60   61   66   67   75   79
...           ...    ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
13596  2022-01-04  22:50  17  18  22  26  27  ...   64   65   71   72   73   76   80
13597  2022-01-05  15:00   1   5   8  14  15  ...   47   54   59   67   70   72   76
13598  2022-01-05  22:50   6   7  14  15  16  ...   54   55   59   61   70   71   80
13599  2022-01-06  15:00   9  10  11  17  28  ...   51   55   65   67   72   76   78
13600  2022-01-06  22:50   1   2   6   9  11  ...   51   52   54   67   68   73   75
```

I have found this article:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

But I am trying to develop a modified version of that 1D CNN model by using **softmax** function on the last layer and **SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()** as loss function and also by adding new functions to that code making it different.

This is my code so far and the model I am trying to build and use:

```
# multivariate output 1d cnn example
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pandas as pd
# multivariate output 1d cnn example
from numpy import array
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.losses import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


# Define the Required Callback Function
class printlearningrate(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end (self, epoch, logs={}):
        optimizer = self.model.optimizer
        lr = K.eval(optimizer.lr)
        Epoch_count = epoch + 1
        print('\n', "Epoch:", Epoch_count, ', Learning Rate: {:.7f}'.format(lr))


printlr = printlearningrate()


# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences (sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences) - 1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)


df = pd.read_csv('DrawsDB.csv')

print(df)
# df['Time'] = df[['Day', 'Hour']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
df.insert(0, 'Time', df[['Day', 'Hour']].agg(' '.join, axis=1))
df.drop(columns=['Day', 'Hour'], inplace=True)
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
print(df)

numpy_array = df.to_numpy()

print(type(numpy_array))
print(numpy_array)

# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 10
# convert into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(numpy_array, n_steps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

# the dataset knows the number of features, e.g. 2
n_features = X.shape[2]
# Reduce learning rate when nothing happens to lower more the loss:
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.9888888888888889,
                              patience=10, min_lr=0.0000001, verbose=1)

epochs = 10
# saving best model every epoch with ModelCheckpoint:
checkpoint_filepath = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Saved\\CheckPoint\\model\\'
model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    monitor='loss',
    save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=True,
    verbose=1)

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation=LeakyReLU(), input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation=LeakyReLU()))
model.add(Dense(n_features))
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=0.09), loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error])

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=2, callbacks=[printlr, reduce_lr, model_checkpoint_callback])
```

**split_sequences** function like its name says it is splitting the database by taking just N rows from it as input and trying to predict the all N+1 row from the database as the output.

However, I think there is a problem because I am getting this error every time I am trying to run the python script:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,20] and labels shape [640]
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
 (defined at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:5114)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1228]
```

Any idea on how to fix this problem, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the shape of `y`?

Comment: @AloneTogether After running this piece of code: # convert into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(numpy_array, n_steps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)     It prints: (13591, 10, 20) (13591, 20) So, the shape of y is 13591, 20.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Sorry for being late. Just checked the site today.

Comment: Juts did it right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the labels are integers, they have the wrong shape for `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy).
Try converting your `y` to one-hot encoded labels:

```
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=20)
```

and change your loss function to `CategoricalCrossentropy`:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=0.09), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error])
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yes, the labels are the numbers (integers) themselves. Could you explain to me, please, why choose CategoricalCrossentropy instead of SparseCategoricalCrossentropy? Sparse is not better in this case? What would be the difference? Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, one more question please: On this line of code reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss',factor=0.9888888888888889,
                              patience=10, min_lr=0.0000001, verbose=1) Should I set monitor on the 'loss' or on the accuracy or on which one from the metrics metrics=['accuracy', mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error] should I set to monitor in order to choose the best model weights in this case since I am using Softmax and not 'relu' ? Thank you so much again for everything!

Comment: I would monitor `loss` or `validation loss` if you have a validation dataset.

Comment: "If you are working with sparse integer labels, where each sample belongs to one of 20 classes {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...,20}, then you can use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy but your labels' shape has to be (samples, 1) and not )samples, 20)" ---> What do you think it is best method in this case (I am trying to predict keno numbers 20/80. I know it sounds as a joke but just to learn machine learning and for fun and to learn.) ? Thank you! Please explain why it would be better in a way or another? Thank you again!

Comment: There are no preferences there.. it all depends on what your data looks like, but yeah it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for everything! I am going to mark your solution as the best.

Comment: Forgot to ask you something that come into my mind a bit later: It should be num_classes=20 or num_classes=80 since you are trying to predict 20 numbers at once but there are 80 numbers in total and they are drawn only 20 of them as the game is lotto 20/80 ? Thank you!

Comment: But it should be 20 or 80? I'm a bit confussed. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is hard to say without further details, but I would start off with 20.